# How can I past a variable in request with HTTParty?

Tags: ruby, httparty

I need to generate a value using Post and pass this value in the query and delete. How to do this?

Is it possible to pass the value of a variable directly in the `def retrieve` method of request get or delete?
[I want to use the same value generated in the var that stores the faker gem and pass both get and delete.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zidpn.jpg)

```
require 'HTTParty'
require 'httparty/request'
require 'httparty/response/headers'

class Crud    
  include HTTParty

  def create 
    @@codigo = Faker::Number.number(digits: 5)
    @nome    = Faker::Name.first_name
    @salario = Faker::Number.decimal(l_digits: 4, r_digits: 2)
    @idade   = Faker::Number.number(digits: 2)

    @base_url  = 'http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/create'

    @body = {
      "id":@@codigo,  
      "name":@nome,
      "salary":@salario,
      "age":@idade        
    }.to_json

    @headers = {
        "Accept": 'application/vnd.tasksmanager.v2',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    @@request = Crud.post(@base_url, body: @body, headers: @headers) 
 end

  def retrieve
    self.class.get('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employee/1') 
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just parse response from API and use fetched id. You don't need to pass id when create an employee, it is generated automatically

```rb
class Crud
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1'

  def create 
    nome    = Faker::Name.first_name
    salario = Faker::Number.decimal(l_digits: 4, r_digits: 2)
    idade   = Faker::Number.number(digits: 2)
    #note, you should pass body as JSON string
    body = { name: nome, salary: salario, age: idade }.to_json

    headers = {
      'Accept' => 'application/vnd.tasksmanager.v2',
      'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    }

    self.class.post('/create', body: body, headers: headers) 
  end

  def retrieve(id)
    self.class.get("/employee/#{ id }")
  end 
end

> client = Crud.new 
> response = client.create
> id = JSON.parse(response)['id']
> client.retrieve(id)
```

Please, read about variables in ruby - what is the difference between local, instance and global variables. Global variables should be used in rare case, more often you need instance/local ones.

Comment: First of all you are an ANGEL !. I will test this soution and promise you that I will study hard !. I believe this solution works to delete too right ?.

Comment: @saulik thank you :) Now I understood, what you need, I've updated the answer. It works the same for `delete`

Comment: Vasi, 
changed as you did, the request Create works correctly, but the query failed.  Create:  {"name":"Donovan","salary":"3204.98","age":"34","id":"126446"} -- OK    retrieve: self.class.get("/employee/#{id}")    The following error is displayed: "wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) (ArgumentError)"  ..thank you, thank you....

Comment: @saulik looks like you forgot to pass `id` when called `retrieve`. Check my answer again, please - `client.retrieve(id)`. About TW - it's not how StackOverflow works, the main goal is to share knowledge

Comment: I don't know why but the returned id is always a number after the current ID.                 I ran again:                                                                                                 _manter_user.create
   expect(_manter_user.create.code).to eq (200)
  puts _manter_user.create.body
  response = _manter_user.create
  puts id = JSON.parse(response)['id']
{"name":"Elsie","salary":"4159.51","age":"45","id":"136118"} - Id request
      136119  - Recovered Id

Comment: I think I've gotten a little clearer now.  Thank for While!

Comment: I need to automatically get the same id generated in request, I'm generating automated tests.